# How do I add numbers I've iterated into a list to a string?

Tags: python

I've got a tiny project I'm working on: I'm trying to make a "grading" program that lets you enter the number of exams, the scores for each exam, and then prints the results.

What I'm looking to do:

Enter the number of tests:
use that number with the string "Exam #: " to number each test.

I've gotten as far as sticking the input from "Enter the number of tests:" into a list..(looks like [0,1,2,3,4.. etc] now I'm trying to combine each of those list numbers with the above string and nothing I'm trying is working.. suggestions?

This is what I came up with, and its output:

```
test1 = int(input('How many tests are there? '))
test2 = []
for number in range(test1):
    test2.append(number)

for number2 in test2:
    print('Exam #:' + str(number2))
```

(inputting "5" here)

```
Exam #:0
Exam #:1
Exam #:2
Exam #:3
Exam #:4
```

exactly what I needed!

Comment: `'Exam #: ' + str(testnum)`

Comment: There are lots of ways to format numbers into a string, that's just one of them.

Comment: This was helpful, I think the str() was what was holding me up for some reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something link this

```python
num_exams = int(input('Enter the number of exams: '))
exam_scores = [int(input(f'Enter score for exam #{n+1}: ')) for n in range(num_exams)]
print(f'Average score: {sum(exam_scores) / num_exams:0.2f}')
```

Comment: Well that's exactly what I was trying to do, and a much simpler way of doing it than I was going about it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'd want to collect inputs for the number of tests and then all the test scores. Then to print the test scores you could do something like

```
for test in range(numTests):
    print('Exam #' + (test+1) + ': ' + testScores[test])
```

The (test+1) is so that you could have the same variable manage the test number as well as the index in the test array. For example, it could print

```
Exam #1: 82
Exam #2: 93
Exam #3: 87
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is needed for your program, but you can iterate through all your values in a list with a for loop. This allows you you to access each value and perform some set of commands on that value. So in this example, we will access each value and then print it. Print can take multiple arguments. It will print out each argument with a space in between.

```
for examNumber in myList:
   print ('Exam', examNumber)
```